# Please help me accurately figure out the kana or kanji for a colloquial phrase said in an anime?

Tags: colloquial-language, phrases, kana, anime, listening

(I can change the question if it's too vague. )

I'm trying to practice my listening comprehension by listening to anime and not fully paying attention to subtitles. For the most part I can understand them but every now and then there will be something that I suppose is so colloquial that I can't find references to the word anywhere. I like looking up the more natural ways people would say things than just book/dictionary forms. (I've been told I'm too stiff...)

One of these is from the anime 'March comes in like a Lion' season 2 episode 13 on Netflix. (For the source reference)

Rei the main character sits down about 14:50 and says under his breath something like "iya (or iye) korakusho" like when you'd sit down and go "oh boy/man" or "ah whew" or something to that effect in English, this traslates it as "ooph" in the subtitles though...

I've heard this in many other anime over the years and it's one I can never find a reference to or how it's used exactly.

Ive tried every single similar combination I could think of of kana/kanji to research and I can only think that crowd sourcing is my last option. I know this forum is very strict but I hope that my obscure/colloquial reference can be answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the subtitles on Netflix, it's よっこらしょっと, which seems to be a variation on よっこらしょ, which you can find [in dictionaries](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%82%88%E3%81%A3%E3%81%93%E3%82%89%E3%81%97%E3%82%87). As you understood, it's something said when exerting effort.

[image]

Comment: That was fast! Was that on US Netflix? I didn't even think to look and see if it had Japanese subtitles, it's like 2 in the morning! I'm embarrassed 

Comment: @Kyoumimasu I'm in Japan, so I'm not sure what is on the US Netflix. It probably isn't available there.

Comment: ありがとうございます ‍♀️ the phrase I hear most here is よし or よっしゃ〜 or おいしょ〜 from Japanese-Americans 